# How does a kernel driver talk with another device?

Tags: unix, embedded, driver, i2c

I have an FPGA board with unix-based firmware. I need write out the program to run on this firmware that will send commands to some devices via I<sup>2</sup>C bus and will receive responses. I use for this special character file in Unix that i map in my program and write to it special commands & read from it responses. Each memory area in this mapped memory corresponds specific register of the FPGA which specified in Unix-based firmware (as i understand).

So, the question is the next one. As i understand, when i write some command to that mapped memory region of the special character file the kernel calls certain driver to handle bytes that I've written and send them through I<sup>2</sup>C bus (for example). Am I right? If so, is there some guarantee that the response from that device will be buffered and I will be able to read it from the mapped region in any time? Or does it depend on implementation specific driver?

I'm sorry if question is not clear some way, I am a newbie in this stuff.

Comment: I think it belongs to the FPGA configuration and specific drivers... BTW there are no info enough to answer to your question. take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer clarifies me the point actually. I'm afraid this is the all info i have as of now, so i will try to dig deeper...

Comment: You could start writing the board name and the SDK and all other info relevant info about kernel/drivers/FPGA config...

Comment: It's xilinx's FPGA, has firmware based on Angstrom OS. Can you clarify please what you mean under FPGA config? Specified registers?

Comment: FPGA does not use firmware but configuration data. Only some FPGA can have firmware, like the one with Neos core

Comment: Oh, okay. I may still be getting confused with terms

Comment: Why don't you look at how for example Linux typically manages the I2C bus engine and makes it available at low level (or for some peripherals higher level) when running on an embedded board that has one?

Comment: that was an idea, but it couldn't give guarantee that in case of mine with modified angstrom OS. So i wanted to know if there is some "standard" on how the Linux driver should manage i2c bus or it depends on implementation so it can be different in my case. I don't have source code of the OS unfortunately.

Comment: that in case of mine with modified angstrom OS it would operates the same way*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unanswerable without documentation of the specific system in question